# Restoring nuget packages of project with the http version of nuget.org using the dotnet cli

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore, dotnet-cli

I am trying to `dotnet restore` my .net core project, however i cannot access http**s**://api.nuget.org/* from my current workstation (so the command just times out), accessing **http**://api.nuget.org/* however is possible.

Is there a way to make the `dotnet` cli use the http version of nuget.org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `NuGet.Config` file in your repository (or create it using `dotnet new nugetconfig`) and add the feed like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="http://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
 </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

You can also update your global NuGet.Config file to match. It is located in `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config` on *nix and `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` on Windows.

Comment: I did what you said and executed `dotnet restore --configfile nuget.config`

Unfortunately, it seems to still use https.
"The HTTP request to 'GET http**s**://api.nuget.or" ... timed out (x100)

Comment: it should pick up the nuget.config file from the current working directory or above. you can try a different key though. did modifying the global nuget.config yield the same result?

Comment: yes same result. I found out why though: if you go to the http version, all link in the response are http**s**, which causes all consequent requests to fail ... at this point I don't think there is an easy workaround. https not fully working from this network is the real problem ...

Comment: I marked this as answer as it may help people with a simmilar problem